# Trouble making my Javascript work with HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to learn how to use JavaScript by making a simple form, but it isn't working like I'd expect it to.
I wrote some verification functions which I thought would work, but I can't figure out why they aren't.
I can make an alert run through my Verify function, but the actual functions I've called won't run.

Here is my full code.

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" />
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>


<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="Header">
            <div id="Link_One" class="Link">

                <p> Link One </p>

            </div>

            <div id="Link_Two" class="Link">

                <p> Link Two </p>

            </div>

            <div id="Link_Three" class="Link">

                <p> Link Three </p>

            </div>

            <div id="Link_Four" class="Link">

                <p> Link Four </p>

            </div>

            <div id="Link_Five" Class="Link">

                <p> Link Five </p>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="Column_Left">

            <form>
                <p> Name: </p>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="Name_Input">
                <p id="Name_Error"> Please enter a valid name. </p>
                </br> </br> </br>
                <p> Age: </p>
                <input type="number" name="age" id="Age_Input">
                <p id="Age_Error"> Please enter a valid age. </p>
                </br> </br> </br>
                <p> Email: </p>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="Email_Input">
                <p id="Email_Error"> Please enter a valid email. </p>
                </br> </br>
                <button type="button" id="Submit_Button" onclick="Verify()"> Submit </button>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div id="Column_Right">

        </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

* {
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}

#wrapper {
height: 100%;
width: 80%;
max-width: 1500px;
min-width: 800 px;
background-color: black;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px black;
}

#Column_Left {
height: 100%;
width: 50%;
background-color: LightGreen;
float: left;
}

#Column_Right {
height: 100%;
width: 50%;
background-color: Purple;
float: right;
}

#Header {
height: 10%;
width: 100%;

}

#Link_One {
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
height: 100%;
width: 19.5%;
background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

#Link_Two {
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
height: 100%;
width: 19.5%;
background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

#Link_Three {
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
height: 100%;
width: 19.5%;
background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

#Link_Four {
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
height: 100%;
width: 19.5%;
background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

#Link_Five {
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
height: 100%;
width: 19.5%;
background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.Link {
border: 1px solid black;
}

.Link p {
line-height: 400%;
}

#Name_Error {
display: none;
}

#Age_Error {
display: none;
}

#Email_Error {
display: none;
}
```

Javascript

```
var Age_Reg = /[0-9]/;
var Email_Reg = /^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/;
var Name_Reg = /[^A-Za-z0-9_'-]/;

function Name_Verify() {

    var Name = document.getElementById("Name_Input").value;

    if (Name_Reg.test(Name)) {

    } else {
        document.getElementById("Name_Error").style.display = inline;
}
}


function Age_Verify() {

    var Age = document.getElementById("Age_Input").value; 

    if (Age_Reg.test(Age)) {

    } else {
        document.getElementById("Age_Error").style.display = inline;
} 
}

function Email_Verify() {

    var Email = document.getElementById("Email_Input").value;

    if (Email_Reg.test(Email)) {

    } else {
        document.getElementById("Email_Error").style.display = inline;
} 
}

function Verify() {
    Name_Verify();
    Age_Verify();
    Email_Verify();
}
```

Comment: do you get any errors? what do you see in the console? also `document.getElementById("Age_Error").style.display = inline;` is not going to work `inline` is a string and it should be `'inline'`. notice the quotes.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: inline is not defined

Comment: Oh my gosh, I can't believe that I didn't notice that. I feel so dumb right now.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: you're most welcome :)

Comment: Another new person question.....How do I go about closing this question?

Comment: Oh I see, I was trying to figure out how to accept a comment. I'll go ahead and select an actual answer. As you can tell I'm pretty new here!

Comment: you can accept @Jamen's answer since mine is just a comment or I can post mine.

Comment: I went ahead and accepted the answer submitted by Jamen.

Comment: Thank you again for showing me the problem. I stared at this for about thirty minutes and didn't notice the missing quotes.

Comment: glad was able to help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to reference `inline` as if it were a variable, I assume you mean to use quotes...  `"inline"`

Comment: Shouldn't need the the ```window.onload``` wrapper necessarily. The functions fire when the submit button is clicked, at which point the DOM should be loaded already.